# D7 doesn't sent mail after user registration

Tags: debugging, email, drupal, registration

I have a local site on Drupal 7.21. The problem is it doesn't sent mail after registration. It still sends "lost password" messages, as well as contact form messages.
To debug it I've added a _mail_alter to track messages using dd() and dpm() functions. And added this code to settings.php:
$conf['mail_system'] = array('default-system' => 'DevelMailLog',);

And $message contains no info about registration mail. **How can I debug what is going on?**

P.S. I don't know if it is important. On REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION tab on config page (admin/config/people/accounts) I selected these option: Visitors can register accounts, but require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Notify user when account is activated" is also checked. It's located under the Account activation tab on the Account settings config page (admin/config/people/accounts).

If you're creating users via admin/people/create, there's a similar checkbox you'll need to check.

Comment: I have this checkbox checked, but still it makes no difference